# ng-repeat and selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes that I need to mark as checked based on a PHP array

```
<?
    $selected ['1', '100', '250'];
?>

<script>
 $scope.articles = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "100",
    "250",
    "500"
]
</script>

<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="article in articles">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="?" id="{{article}}">
    </div>
</ul>
```

the problem is that I don´t know how to "connect" the php array with the angularjs part. I can echo the php array but not sure how to pass it to JS

thank you.

Comment: Why don't make a service (PHP) which will tell you that info (`['1', '100', '250']`), call it from angular `$http.get` and, (from here it is too easy) update the values accordingly in the view?

Comment: Don't do that please, create a service and retrieve that array from backend.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comment by @Ele, you should have it in angularjs service, fetch it from the backend. Have a method in your service, pass the article.Id to it, that service will check if passed id is present in the array or not, based on that your checkbox will be set.

**Template:**

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isArticlePresent(article.Id)" id="{{article}}">
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.isArticlePresent = function(id){
return service.isArticlePresent(id);
};
```

**Service**

```
this.isArticlePresent = function (id) {
    //Write your logic, and return true/false
}
```